# Physical behavior of fluid changes as i change resolution, so what is the proper workflow?

Tags: baking, mantaflow

I'm trying to wrap my head around the best workflow when dealing with fluid simulations. Everyone says to use low resolutions to preview it but when I increase the resolution for the final bake, it almost always never looks similar. The fluid flows too slowly, or sometimes sudden explosions happen. So how do you guys preview properly before doing a final bake?

Comment: Well that's more a question of opinion with no distinct solution. First of all, it is absolutely normal that the fluid reacts differently. It's as simple as that: you cannot preview how a high resolution fluid with very small voxels flows for example through a hole by simulating it with low resolution and voxels that are much too big to pass the hole. But what to do against it? That's the opinion-based part. I usually never preview with too low resolutions, I always start with medium resolutions - and for the final render I try to get away with not too high resolutions.

Comment: understood, but why does the fluid become slower as the resolution increase? Im not talking about the viewport display lagging but rather the particles themselves. Apologies for my ignorance

Comment: More surface, more interaction with surrounding geometry, more friction...